# Whats the difference between PyPy and PyPI

Tags: python, pypi, pypy

This is probably a really stupid question but whats the difference between 'PyPy' and 'PyPI'?  Are they the same thing?

Comment: This was probably downvoted because you didn't google it, but the irony is that googling it brought me here.

Comment: Yeah, haha.  Guess my silly question helps someone.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[PyPy](https://pypy.org/) is an alternative implementation of python:

> PyPy is a fast, compliant alternative implementation of the Python
>   language (2.7.13 and 3.5.3). It has several advantages and distinct
>   features: Speed: thanks to its Just-in-Time compiler, Python programs
>   often run faster on PyPy. (What is a JIT compiler?) “If you want your
>   code to run faster, you should probably just use PyPy.” — Guido van
>   Rossum (creator of Python) Memory usage: memory-hungry Python programs
>   (several hundreds of MBs or more) might end up taking less space than
>   they do in CPython. Compatibility: PyPy is highly compatible with
>   existing python code. It supports cffi and can run popular python
>   libraries like twisted and django. Stackless: PyPy comes by default
>   with support for stackless mode, providing micro-threads for massive
>   concurrency. As well as other features.

---

[PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) is the repository for python packages, modules and libraries that you can install.

> The Python Package Index is a repository of software for the Python
>   programming language. There are currently 120970 packages